# MongoDB $elemMatch on ALL embedded documents/subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following students collections:

```js
[
  {
    nickname: 'Hafez',
    classes: [
      { name: 'Physics', score: 5 },
      { name: 'Math', score: 10 }
    ]
  },
  {
    nickname: 'Nada',
    classes: [
      { name: 'Physics', score: 8 },
      { name: 'Math', score: 9 }
    ]
  },
  {
    nickname: 'Sam',
    classes: [
      { name: 'Physics', score: 6 },
      { name: 'Math', score: 10 }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to get the students that scored **at least** 7 in **all** classes.

The following filter gives me all documents because they all have scored 7 in **some** class. I want to find them only if they scored 7 in **all** classes.

```js
Student.find({ 'classes.score': { $gte: 7 } }); // incorrectly finds all students.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is to inverse the condition and do a `$not`.

The following says: find me a student who has not scored less than 7 in any class, which is the equivalent of "find me all students who scored higher than 7 on **all** classes.

```js
Student.find({
  'classes.score': {
    $not: {
      $lt: 7
    }
  }
}); // correctly logs only `Nada`
```

Admittedly, the readability of this is quite difficult to grasp and you'll often have to explain it to your peers why you're doing this the way you are, but I couldn't find any other way to achieve what I am trying to achieve.

Here's a mongo playground to play with this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/4hI3j7dliYw